# Error while applying OWSM policies on Web service created from Jdeveloper 11g (SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\jps-config.xml)

Tags: java, web-services, oracle11g

I created sample class `Testws` with one simple method `sayHi(String name)` that simply showing welcome message. The target is to create web service application for this class and applying OWSM policies.

All the needed file is generated from `Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7` and I added the `oracle/wss_username_token_client_policy` to the client side in `TestwsPortClient`. Problem is that when I run the main method from TestwsPortClient I got the following error:

```
SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\jps-config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Although I tried (But it did not work) to set the system propriety to find the missing file as follow:

```
System.setProperty("oracle.security.jps.config",  
                       "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\JDeveloper\\system11.1.1.7.40.64.93\\DefaultDomain\\config\\fmwconfig\\jps-config.xml");
```

Here is the Client Class `TestwsPortClient`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    testwsService = new TestwsService();  
    SecurityPoliciesFeature securityFeatures =  
        new SecurityPoliciesFeature(new String[] { "oracle/wss_username_token_client_policy" });  
    Testws testws = testwsService.getTestwsPort(securityFeatures);  
    // Add your code to call the desired methods.  
    System.setProperty("oracle.security.jps.config",  
                       "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\JDeveloper\\system11.1.1.7.40.64.93\\DefaultDomain\\config\\fmwconfig\\jps-config.xml");  

    List<CredentialProvider> credProviders =new ArrayList<CredentialProvider>();  
    String username = "weblogic";  
    String password = "weblogic1";  
    CredentialProvider cp =new ClientUNTCredentialProvider(username.getBytes(), password.getBytes());  
    credProviders.add(cp);  
    Map<String, Object> rc = ((BindingProvider)testws).getRequestContext();  
    rc.put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST, credProviders);  
    testws.sayHi("Salman");  
}
```

Here the exception stack trace:
*Note: the stack trace is too long this is just part of it where I think it will gives an idea about the error*

```
SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\jps-config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)  
SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\jps-config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)  
INFO: WSM-09004 Component auditing cannot be initialized.  
INFO: Recipient Alias property not configured in the policy. Defaulting to encrypting with signers certificate.  
WARNING: JPS-00065 Jps platform factory creation failed. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.se.JpsSEPlatformFactory.  
WARNING: JPS-00065 Jps platform factory creation failed. Reason: {0}.  
 ......
  at $Proxy34.sayHi(Unknown Source)  
  at test.TestwsPortClient.main(TestwsPortClient.java:44)  
Caused by: oracle.security.jps.JpsException: JPS-00065: Jps platform factory creation failed. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.se.JpsSEPlatformFactory.  
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.JpsPlatformFactory$2.run(JpsPlatformFactory.java:197)  
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.JpsPlatformFactory$2.run(JpsPlatformFactory.java:190)  
........
```